# Check specific view controller is open in Foreground in App delegate

Tags: ios, navigation

i have implemented push notification in my app. Now when my app is in foreground i want to check either user is on chat screen or not,I have tried various code but it isn't work. My chat screen comes in this scenario,
First i have tab bar controller under my last tab when i click it open the chat screen, Tabbar Controller --> Last Tab VC --> Chat VC. I want to check in app delegate if user is in foreground and notification arrives, either user is on chat screen or not.How i can check that? This is my code through which i'm testing but it isn't working,

```
 if let chatViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatDetailViewController") as? ChatDetailViewController, let tabBar = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBar") as? UITabBarController {

        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: chatViewController)

        tabBar.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
        tabBar.viewControllers = [navigationController]

       if tabBar.viewControllers == [navigationController]
       {
           completionHandler([])
        }
        else
       {
          completionHandler([.alert,.sound])
        }
    }
```

This is my flow for screen,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are actually creating a new instance of `ChatViewController`. Instead, you need get the currently open ViewController instance and check if it's `ChatViewController`.

This could be a solution. I suppose `UITabBarController` is the root view controller of your app.

```
if let tabBar = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {

        if let chatViewController = tabBar.selectedViewController as? ChatDetailViewController {
            completionHandler([])
            print("Chat VC is on top")
        }
        else {
            completionHandler([.alert,.sound])
            print("Chat VC is not on top")
        }

    }
```

And if, the Tab bar controller holds a navigation controller(probably it should), then following code should work.

```
if let tabBar = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {

        if let navVC = tabBar.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController, let chatViewController = navVC.viewControllers.last as? ChatDetailViewController {
            completionHandler([])
            print("Chat VC is on top")
        }
        else {
            completionHandler([.alert,.sound])
            print("Chat VC is not on top")
        }

    }
```

Comment: Bro its crashing with this error, Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 9223372036854775807 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]' . @Roohul

Comment: It throwing error on navigation controller code, Ambiguous use of 'topViewController' . @Roohul

Comment: Do you have a navigation controller for the chat view controller? I mean the tab bar points to the navigation controller?

Comment: i have tab bar controller and VC under tab bar are under navigation controller. @Roohul

Comment: Just edited the answer. Would you please try again?

Comment: I have added image please check. @Roohul

Comment: Bro ur code is showing error on this line, let chatViewController = navVC.topViewController as? ChatDetailViewController. on navVC. with error, Ambiguous use of 'topViewController'. @Roohul

Comment: Edited the code once again, please try.
Actually, the code is just a guess. The image you have shared is not clear when zoomed, I don't have exact idea how your navigation hierarchy is planned. You can get an idea from the above code and change as per the view controller hierarchy of your app.

Comment: Bro my hierarchy is this, TabBarr Controller --> Nav Controller --> MessageVC --> ChatDetailVC. I want to check if user is on ChatDetailVC or not. @Roohul

Comment: I'm getting error on this line of ur code, let chatViewController = navVC.viewControllers.last as? ChatDetailViewController . 
error is Ambiguous use of 'topViewController' . @Roohul